# Appium's accessibleId/TestID not working with react-navigation's headerTransparent property

Tags: react-native, testing, appium, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am trying to write automation test cases using Appium for my react-native application where I am using react-navigation header, the test cases were able to access the accessibleId/TestID earlier but now it stopped working, it is because I have added backgroundImage to my react-navigation header due to which I have to use headerTransparent property and as per the below thread, it will not work.

Not sure if there is any fix for it, we have to make it work in our application

link:- https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5521

Comment: Have u found any solution on this?